# Defining priority of operations in limits with stacking fractions

Tags: limits, fractions

I need to evaluate the following limit :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2}$$

Using L'Hospital rule, I get this result (which I'm pretty sure is good)

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{2x}{x^2+1}}{2x}$$

Now, I'm not sure how I must evaluate this. Either as :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{x^2+1}*\frac{1}{2x} = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

or

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} 2x*(\frac{x^2+1}{2x})^{-1} = \frac{4x^2}{x^2+1}$$

According to most of the tools I use to validate my maths, the 1st result is the good one, but I can't figure out why, am I simply missing a set of parenthesis in my equation?

Comment: Yes, the first one is correct.  $(a/b)/c\ne a/(b/c)$

Comment: @choco_addicted I'm not sure I understand what you mean, indeed I'm probably confused.

Comment: Ah, I understood that there is no $\lim$ notation is not important. The point was how to compute fraction. Sorry for misunderstanding and I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just elementary algebra:

$${{a\over b}\over c} = {a\over b\cdot c}$$

i.e., $a/b$ divided by $c$ equals $a$ divided by $bc$.  Thus, the first result which you have obtained is the correct one.  In the second equation, you wrote

$$2x\cdot\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)^{-1}$$
instead of the correct
$${1\over 2x}\cdot\left(\frac{x^2+1}{2x}\right)^{-1}$$